# Add Encoding Filter to JFileChooser in Java

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

How do I add encoding option "UTF-8" to my JFileChooser save dialog box.

```
  JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
  FileNameExtensionFilter filter1 = new FileNameExtensionFilter("TEXT", ".txt");

        fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter1);
        fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Specify a file to save"); 
              int returnVal = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
              if ( returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION )
               {

                    File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
               //do something
               }
```

Comment: What do you mean an "encoding option"? Please give an example

Comment: encoding UTF-8 format is what I need to write and save the text file.

Comment: `JFileChooser` supports an accessory, it's probably the best you will get, unless you want to supply an additional dialog

Comment: how do I set it to UTF-8 format? It's taking ANSI as default I guess

Comment: can you answer this with code sample

Answer (score 1):

Using standard Java:

```
String aString = "Test\nWithNewline";
try {
    Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                      new FileOutputStream("outfilename"), "UTF-8"));
    out.write(aString);
    out.close();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Using Apache Commons:

```
File f = new File("outfilename"); 
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(f, aString, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: I'm using FileWriter                                                                           'FileWriter writer1 = new FileWriter(file, true);
   writer1.write("Channel Details:"+sCurrentLine);
          writer1.write("\r\n");   // write new line
          writer1.close();'

Comment: How do I include UTF-8 in this

Comment: I'm reading the text in UTF-8, but writing that to a file in UTF-8 is not happening

Comment: @Scitech FileWriter doesn't give direct API for encoding. It's messy.

Comment: Take a look at the example program located at the following link:  http://www.herongyang.com/Swing/JEditorPane-File-Chooser-Dialog-Box.html

Comment: @Scitech Updated code as a verifiable example. Check now to create a file containing 2 lines.

Comment: I have to use the same file across many methods. How do I achieve this

Comment: Pass the file as an argument or declare it with a public getter